# un-representable DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have method which expects two datetime parameters

```
public  void SomeReport(DateTime TimeFrom, DateTime TimeTo)
{
    // ommited 
    TimeFrom.ToString("ddMMyy"), TimeTo.ToString("ddMMyy")));
    // ommited
}
```

When I'm sending this params

```
 DateTime TimeTo = DateTime.Now;
 DateTime TimeFrom = new DateTime().AddHours(-1);
```

This error occured:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`new DateTime()` is `01/01/0001 00:00:00` which is also `DateTime.MinValue`.

You are subtracting one hour from that.

Guessing you are trying to subtract an hour from the `TimeTo` value:

```
var TimeFrom = TimeTo.AddHours(-1);
```

Comment: Yeh !! I also struct in it .Got it tat default instance of datetime provede MinValue of datetime !

Answer (score 14):

`new DateTime()` returns the minimum representable `DateTime`; adding `-1` hours to this results in a `DateTime` that can't be represented.

You probably want `DateTime TimeFrom = TimeTo.AddHours(-1);`

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
DateTime TimeTo = DateTime.Now;
DateTime TimeFrom = TimeTo.AddHours(-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

creating a `DateTime` with `new DateTime()` gives you a `DateTime` with `DateTime.MinValue`... from this you actually can't subtract anything... otherwise you get the exception you got... see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Look you date or time data .There not enough digits for date or time Example date must be  8 digit 20140604 and time 6 digit like this  180203.For this reason you are getiing error.
i get this error too and find time  18000 and change this to 180000 problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `TimeFrom` holds the datetime from which -1 can not be added. You can either invoke

```
DateTime TimeFrom = TimeTo .AddHours(-1);
```

or

```
DateTime TimeFrom = new DateTime().now.AddHours(-1);
```

Both of them yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

In my error, I used the time as 24:00 instead of 00:00