# SSRS report service #error when add datetime with negative number

Tags: datetime, reporting-services

I have an expression like below:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!fromCreatedDateUtc.Value),"",
Format(Dateadd(DateInterval.Minute, Parameters!dtOffset.Value, Parameters!fromCreatedDateUtc.Value), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"))
```

With condition:

```
Parameters!fromCreatedDateUtc.Value = null
Parameters!dtOffset.Value = -300
```

It always shows "#ERROR" when the `dtoffset` value is negative.

Please help me on this.

Comment: I put this code:
`=IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!fromCreatedDateUtc.Value) and IsNothing(Parameters!thruCreatedDateUtc.Value),"",
Format(Dateadd(DateInterval.Minute, Parameters!dtOffset.Value, IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!fromCreatedDateUtc.Value), Now(), Parameters!fromCreatedDateUtc.Value)), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"))`

It works

Comment: Also be aware that both the true and false statements of the `IIF()` are evaluated, so that may be another avenue to look at as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Report Cells are showing #Error, try following.  Try to get exception details first.

**Option 1**

Sometimes some values in rendered report cells are shown as #Error.  These are runtime SSRS errors.  I am not sure whether the details regarding these errors are shown in VS report viewer. But another way to get exception details is to put try catch block aroud the expression of the cell which has runtime error.  In the catch block, exception details can be printed out.

These errors will also be displayed in Build > Output window in following format.

[rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘xxx.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format.

[rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘textbox8.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Preview complete -- 0 errors, 2 warnings

**Option 2**

Wrap your SSRS expression in try catch block and print exception details. You can also use custom function to do so.  Check following article for details.

https://sqlserverbiblog.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/using-custom-code-functions-in-reporting-services-reports/

Comment: Hi murtazat, I can see the error message below the report. it says: "the added or subtracted value results in an un-representable datetime", so I guess it because I subtracting the the null value. But I have put the IIF to handle this. but it still not working.

Comment: In that case, first print plain values of parameters  Parameters!dtOffset.Value and Parameters!fromCreatedDateUtc.Value report cells and see they are not invalid.  In addition to null check, also add empty/blank string check.  Once you are confident, all values are valid, only then go for date manipulation.  I suggest you can do this in custom function (Report Properties > Code).  This would be better than writing a lengthy RDL expression.  Also see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700258/un-representable-datetime for unrepresentable date issue.