# ASP.NET C# using gridview

Tags: c#

When I run this code, I get an error:

> The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime. Parameter name: months

This is my code:

```
protected void pmGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{           
    DateTime grace = 
    Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,"duedate"));
    DateTime grace1 = grace.AddMonths(-6);
    DateTime grace2 = grace.AddMonths(6);

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (DateTime.Today >= grace1 && DateTime.Today < grace)
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
        else if (DateTime.Today >= grace && DateTime.Today < grace2)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow;
        }
        else if (DateTime.Today >= grace2)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any answer

Comment: Looks like you're not reading in the date value properly in your Convert.ToDateTime portion. Have you debugged that this produces an actual DateTime value that you can run the .AddMonths() method? The default value for a DateTime object is 1/1/0001 so perhaps you removing 6 months from that is causing an error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [un-representable DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700258/un-representable-datetime)